# Sum employees based on mapping in another table

Tags: excel-formula

I have one dynamic named range where I have the employees and their opportunities listed. the table also has a subtotal by employee. I have another table where I have a list of teams and the employees on those teams. The two tables are not the same size.
How do I sum up the employee totals from table 1 if they belong on the same team? In other words, how do I get the team total? 
There is a similar question with an answer but when I try to use the sumif based on that answer, i am getting a #value error as the criteria range is not the same size.
Thanks

[image: team map]

Comment: Which one is the Table 1?

Comment: The first 6 rows are table 1

Comment: Need the value for Cisco by summing the values from table 1 in the first 6 rows. Mapping of emp is to team Id from row 9 onwards tells which employees from table 1 to include in the sum.

Comment: 1. Can you share the link for "There is a similar question with an answer .... " by editing & adding it the question post ? (if your data was arranged exactly as the reference question, then the formula should work, but If your data was arranged differently, then need to incorporate that into your formula/approach.)

Comment: 2. You CAN do the "sum up the employee totals from table 1 if they belong on the same team" part. I know you can get the "Team ID by using [this[(https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) on row 9 onwards, but to sum up the employee totals, needs you to apply `sumif()` on the Cisco team per Emp ID data table (which was not shared/shown). Without enough sample data/file, others cannot replicate your case (and further assist).

Comment: You are right, my data is arranged differently. Let me try the index match and sumif and update the post. Thanks

Comment: You may share some sample data (no need to be real), with very similar data structure, and formula.. Then we may proceed accordingly. ( :